# NGINX reverse proxy does not proxy an Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nginx

I am trying to setup a separate API backend for a website that serves on `/mypath` but NGINX doesn't seem to actually proxy requests.

The `sites-enabled` nginx configuration:

```
upstream backend_website {
        server 127.0.0.1:5173;
}

upstream backend_api {
        server 127.0.0.1:5001;
}


# HTTP
#
server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       server_name example.com;

       # Redirect to HTTPS (:443)
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS
#
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass https://backend_website;
        }

        location /mypath {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass https://backend_api;
        }
}
```

The `index.ts` file for the service

```js
import cors from "cors";
import express from "express";
import { config } from "config";
import { MyController } from "controllers/my.controller";
import * as https from "https";
import * as fs from "fs";

const certificate = fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem", "utf8");
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem", "utf8");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use("/", MyController );

const httpsServer = https.createServer({
    cert: certificate,
    key: privateKey
}, app);

httpsServer.listen(config.PORT, "127.0.0.1", () => console.log(`Running api on https://127.0.0.1:${ config.PORT }/`));
```

However, the server does not proxy requests to the API. It works flawlessly on the root path (that one uses Vite), but `/mypath` doesn't work when opening the URL I just get `Cannot GET /mypath`. I opened `127.0.0.1:5001` using [lynx](https://lynx.browser.org/) and it does work. So the problem is somewhere around NGINX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. For some unintuitive reason, you have to specify Express should serve on `/mypath/` even though you already tell that in the NGINX config file.

So this code

```js
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use("/", MyController );

const httpsServer = https.createServer({
    cert: certificate,
    key: privateKey
}, app);

httpsServer.listen(config.PORT, "127.0.0.1", () => console.log(`Running api on https://127.0.0.1:${ config.PORT }/`));
```

Becomes that

```js
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use("/mypath", MyController );

const httpsServer = https.createServer({
    cert: certificate,
    key: privateKey
}, app);

httpsServer.listen(config.PORT, "127.0.0.1", () => console.log(`Running api on https://127.0.0.1:${ config.PORT }/`));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the /etc/nginx/site-enabled/ file

```bash
 cd /etc/nginx/site-enabled/
 sudo nano default
```

```cpp
    location /wishfoundationindia/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }

        location /lms/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:7000/;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }
```

then edit in location function with the help of this pic.
[rfr image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMuk3.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Change your nginx config to this.

```
location  /mypath {
      rewrite /foo/(.*) /$1  break;
      proxy_pass         https://backend_api;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}
```

then try to call `http://example.com/mypath/`